# Запуск tmux в нужной директории

Tags: tmux

При запуске `tmux` эмулятор терминала стартует в домашней директории. Как сменить директорию при старте?

Например, при  `cd ~/myprojects/test_project && tmux` терминал стартует в `~` а хотелось в `test_project`.

**UPD:**

Судя по-всему контекст имеет значение. `tmux` я запуска под **cygwin**, **mintty**. В качестве шелла: **zsh**. Для запуска пытаюсь родить скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh
export WORKDIR='/cygdrive/d/work/'
PROJECT_DIR='cm'
PROJECT_NAME='cm'


PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("New session" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "New session")
            cd $WORKDIR
            if [ ! -d  $PROJECT_DIR ] ; then
                mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
            fi

            cd $PROJECT_DIR

            tmux has-session -t $PROJECT_NAME 2>/dev/null
            if [ "$?" -eq 1 ] ; then
                echo "no session found. configuring..."
                tmux new-session -d -s $PROJECT_NAME

                #configuring windows
                tmux rename-window 'cm'
                tmux split-window -v
                tmux send-keys "cmd.exe" C-m
                tmux select-pane -t 1
                tmux resize-pane -D 20
                tmux send-keys "vim" C-m

                tmux select-window -t $PROJECT_NAME:1
            else
                echo 'session found. connecting ...'
            fi

            tmux attach-session -t $PROJECT_NAME
            break
            ;;
        "Quit")
            break
            ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

переход в нужный каталог

```
            cd $WORKDIR
            if [ ! -d  $PROJECT_DIR ] ; then
                mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
            fi
            cd $PROJECT_DIR
```

выполняется, т.к. `echo $PWD` показывает верный путь.

просто переход в нужный каталог и запуск новой сессии `tmux` запускает шелл в `~`.

Comment: абсолютный путь попробуйте указать.

Comment: нет, не помогает

Comment: Что за терминал стоит? смотрю у себя всё работает. p.s. это в bash_rc я так понимаю?

Comment: @Naumov **mintty** и **zsh**. Попробовал под **bash** - эффекта нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день! Необходимо добавить в переменную среды вашего логинскрипта (~/.bash_profile для bash, ~/.zprofile для zsh, ~/.profile для mintty):

```
export CHERE_INVOKING=1
```

Перелогинится и выполнить еще раз:

```
cd ~/myprojects/test_project && tmux
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.